# Как правильно создать переменные класса из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Сейчас создаю класс с переменными следующим образом:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

class States(StatesGroup):
    State1 = State()
    State2 = State()
    State3 = State()
```

В целевом варианте количество и названия переменных будут меняться и храниться в БД. При запуске приложения я получаю из БД новый список переменных, например:

```
StateList = ['State1', 'State2', 'State3']
```

В результате должны быть созданы переменные State1, State2, State3. Какие есть варианты создания без использования **eval()**?

Comment: Непонятно. Задача в том, чтобы строки из списка были именами переменных?

Comment: Количество и названия переменных будут меняться и храниться в БД. При запуске приложения я получаю из БД новый список переменных, согласно которому их нужно создать.

Comment: может лучше использовать словарь?

Comment: Каждый раз, когда у вас возникает желание динамически создавать именованные переменные - это признак того, что нужно использовать словарь или аналогичную структуру данных. Хотя если очень уж хочется извращений, то можно сделать это через метаклассы или через создание класса через type.

Comment: Наверное, зря я не написал цель) Она следующая: есть список состояний (aiogram) , который может меняться. Он точно хранится в бд. В идеале он вообще может быть изменён без остановки приложения. Нужно как-то подтягивать новые состояния из БД.

Answer (score 0):

Например используя [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr).

`test2.py:`

```
class State:
    pass
```

`test1.py:`

```
import test2

class States:
    pass
ds = set(dir(States))

StateList = ['State1', 'State2', 'State3']
for s in StateList:
    setattr(States, s, test2.State())  # States.State1 = State()

for s in set(dir(States)) - ds:
    print(s, getattr(States, s))
```

`out:`

```
State3 <test2.State object at 0x0000028673C61AF0>
State2 <test2.State object at 0x0000028663538250>
State1 <test2.State object at 0x00000286635E2340>
```